# fastapi Uvicorn server set url instead of ip

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to config the Uvicorn localhost to a url instead of it looking like http://0.0.0.0:8000 to http://dev.app. it would be great if you can point me to the right direction. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Edit **C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts** in Windows or **/etc/hosts** in Linux:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.app
```

Change server port to 80:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def root():
    a = "a"
    b = "b" + a
    return {"hello world": b}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Comment: will it allow me to access the dev.app domain on another computer?

I am working on a pi but im using my windows computer to commit my to the pi.

Comment: **Hosts** should be set on every client machine. Or you must set up your own DNS server. @user629283

Comment: i dont understand, what do you mean?